# Best way of logging a user in C++

Tags: c++, session, visual-c++

I am trying to get into C++ programming so apologise if this is a bit of a stupid question.

I am attempting to create a program in C++ that is linked to a website via the database, that's all sorted. In this program, the user must log into it to be able to use its features, I've also managed to do this fine. My question is, what is the best way of storing that users session so I can refer to their username, display that users settings from the database e.c.t?

I am unsure, but I don't think c++ has session options like in php so I cannot do it that way. I did some googling before I posted this, spent all night trying to find a solution, I found nothing.

My knowledge if c++ is slim and this may sound like a more complicated or unnecessary route to take, but it was thinking of perhaps when the user logs in, to create a txt file storing that users username and then calling on it when I need to refer to that users username for queries and such, then when the user logs out or closes the program it deletes the file. Is that stupid? Forgive me if it is.

Is there better way to go about this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: C++ is certainly not the first language that would spring into mind to solve that kind of problems. Usually it is done with server-side script languages like PHP. Doing an equivalent in C++ will require a ***lot*** more code for little or no gain. No wonder the Google God remained silent on the question. I even wonder if it has been done before :).

Comment: Yeah I did wonder if my choice in languages for this project was the right one. However, I do remember seeing many programs that do something similar to what I am attempting. Is there another language I should be looking towards to achieve this?

Comment: Well any server-side script would do. I personnally use PHP, but you can as well use ASP, ASP.NET, ruby, perl CGI, Node.js, you name it :)

Comment: @kuroineko it needs to be a program, or application that's individual from the website, something the user can download and install onto their computer, like an administrator panel sort if thing. If that makes sense.

Comment: You can use PHP without a web server. You can even build a standalone executable with the PHP runtime embedded (see [Phc-win](http://wiki.swiftlytilting.com/Phc-win) for instance), or execute a bunch of PHP scripts from an Unix-like environment using [phar](https://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php).

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea that was possible. You may have just saved me a headache!

Comment: Glad to have been of some help. You still have quite a bit of work ahead, but it will probably be less painful than what C++ would have put you through :).

Comment: @kuroineko it's all a learning experience for me. :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I read your comments, if it needs to be a stand-alone application, like some sort of client, you could take a look at the C++ libraries I mentioned, but I'd use any higher level language (Java or C# have good documentation and there are many tutorials for creating GUIs, if that's what your're looking for. I think even Python would make a good candidate).

If you really must use C++, your best bet would be to use an existing library to implement your web solution. [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) includes an HTTP server framework, and a library for sockets and other forms of low-level network programming. [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) can also serve your purposes. But this is hardly something I'd recommend to start learning programming, or C++ for that matter.

If you want to learn about web programming, then you should definitely take a look at other languages. PHP or ASP.NET come to mind. AS you learn, you'll most likely also end up writing some form of Javascript. You can find a lot of info out there, just Google for tutorials. A site to get started is [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/), but any site with tutorials will do. Good luck!

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks. I may have to do a little research to see what one of the languages you mentioned will be better for me to use.